# iOS Text field delegate if the value of a text field is programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have tried many an attempts to make this work. After much googling, trial & error, I post this here.

I have a text field whose value is changed when a slider near by is moved.

So in the IBAction sliderChanged, I have this

```
 self.amountTextField.text = self.amountSlider.value
```

Now, I would like to be notified of this change in the text field value. I have tried with quite a few delegates. It so happens that when the text field's value is changed by tapping on the text field and changing it using the keyboard, these delegates are fired. But when the value is changed using the above piece of code, the delegates are not invoked.

I do like to know if theres a possible solution for this, i.e, i would like a delegate to handle the change in the text field value even if its done from code. Would love to have a working example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which delegate do you want called? What does it do?

Comment: Would like to call a delegate in which I can retrieve the new value of the text field and then using it for something else. Tried textFieldDidEndEditing: delegate but it does not get invoked when the text field is changed from code.

Comment: Just call whatever code you call in `textFieldDidEndEditing:` in your sliderChanged method?! You could even call `[textField.delegate textFieldDidEndEditing:textField]`. But I wouldn't do this, because technically your textField was never edited.

Comment: Why do you need to call a delegate method? Why not call the method directly right after setting the text?

Comment: Yup, was dumb from my side. Was stuck and couldnt overlook. You mean to call the actual method directly, right. Thanks man! Just getting used to the ios pattern.

Comment: Delegate methods are never (rarely?) called when you change something explicitly. This is by design to avoid recursion. Imagine what would happen if your delegate method that responds to a change needed to also make a change. Since you know that you made a change, you can choose to call code to handle the change or not as needed.